# jQuery with Rails Extending forms Not Working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I followed [this guide](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html) to implement this functionality to my App,

but it won't work properly, when i click on the Button to clone and add the fields it does nothing, but when i reaload the page it clone one and never more.

I have tried usig j2.coffee, tried changing file to .js, every one of those easy things, but none worked,

= _form.html.erb code

```
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
<% if @task.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@task.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this task from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
     </ul>
   </div>
  <% end %>
  <table >
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <th> <%= f.label :projeto_id, "Projeto da Atividade" %><br> </th>
  <th> <%= f.label :seq, "Raiz Sequencial" %><br> </th>
   <th> <%= f.label :descr, "Descrição da Atividade" %><br> </th>
   <th> <%= f.label :seqpai, "Ramo Sequencial" %><br> </th>
<th>  <%= f.label :hour, "Horas de Execução" %> </th>
<th>  <%= f.label :typo, "Tipo da Atividade" %><br> </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="jqueryform">
<tr name="tr">
<td name="projetoid"> <%= f.grouped_collection_select :projeto_id,     Cliente.order(:name), :projetos, :name, :id, :name, prompt: "Selecionar" %>       </td>
<td name="raiz">     <%= f.number_field :seq %>  </td>
<td name="descr">    <%= f.text_field :descr %> </td>
<td name="seqpai">  <%= f.number_field :seqpai %>  </td>
<td name="hour">    <%= f.number_field :hour %> </td>
<td name="typo">   <%= f.select("typo", {"Analitica" => "Analitica",     "Sintetica" => "Sintetica"}) %> </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
    </table>

   <br>
  <span id="writeroot"></span>
   <br>

    <input type="button" id="moreFields" value="Adicionar Atividade!" />
    <br><br><br>
    <%= f.submit 'Enviar', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>

    <% end %>
```

My tasks.js.coffee code

```
counter = 0

moreFields = ->
  counter++
  newFields = document.getElementById('jqueryform').cloneNode(true)
  newFields.id = ''
  newFields.style.display = 'block'
  newField = newFields.childNodes
  i = 0
  while i < newField.length
    theName = newField[i].name
    if theName
      newField[i].name = theName + counter
    i++
  insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot')
  insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore newFields, insertHere
  return

window.onload = moreFields
```

Comment: coffeescript is space/format sensitive - your indentation needs to be precise.  Also, why is there a quote on your final line of code?

Comment: the quote was in the formatting here, my coffee script is indentationed, when sending the code that it got wrong, ill fix it.

Comment: Are you using Firebug or a similar tool to debug?  You should be able to see Javascript errors in your console when you click the button.  In the guide, it looks like the parent which is the anchor for the insert is the wrapping form but I can't see if that is analogous in your code.

Comment: i'm using normal console of firefox, it shows no erros :( , there's anyway to troubleshoot problems in my RoR about java working correctly?

Comment: Yes if you are not already using it, I strongly recommend Firebug @Joao.  Once installed, there are several resources here on SO to help with how to use.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i'll do it now

Comment: No erros at Firebug either :( Ill Try other tutorials maybe this code is wrong and i can't figure out why

Comment: Tried other guide, but still unsuccessful... disabled turbolinks, didn't helped. even that i had jquery-turbolinks gem installed. Srsly i don't know why nothing work any more...

Comment: Wow sounds frustrating... are you certain your jQuery is being loaded?  When I get to where you are, I typically will use an alert or something to make sure my assumptions are correct (jQuery loaded in page and getting fired etc).

Comment: Maybe, when i put some wrong code on purpose it show errors and dont load the page